# How to set up the position allocator when using Ramdomwaypoint model in NS-3

Tags: c++, ns-3

I tried to alter the example code(third.cc) by replacing the mobility model name(RandomWalk2dMobilityModel) with RandomWaypointMobilityModel. After running the code, it turned out to be an output like

> assert failed. cond="m_position", msg="No position allocator added before using this model"

So basically this is the most relevant code with the error msg

`MobilityHelper mobility;`

`mobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::GridPositionAllocator",`

`"MinX", DoubleValue (0.0),`

`"MinY", DoubleValue (0.0),`

`"DeltaX", DoubleValue (5.0),`

`"DeltaY", DoubleValue (10.0),`

`"GridWidth", UintegerValue (3),`

`"LayoutType", StringValue ("RowFirst"));`

`//  mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::RandomWalk2dMobilityModel",`
  `//  "Bounds", RectangleValue (Rectangle (-50, 50, -50, 50)));`

`mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::RandomWaypointMobilityModel");`
 `mobility.Install (wifiStaNodes);`

`mobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::ConstantPositionMobilityModel");`

`mobility.Install (wifiApNode);`

What I am confused about is before setting mobility model, there has already set up the **position allocator** it worked for randomwalk2d, however, obviously it does not work for randomwaypoint model. So how to deal with it?
I'll appreciate if there is someone who can help me to figure it out.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be actually TWO position allocators when you are using RandomWayPointModel.

- The first, the one you have already used, is for the initial position of the nodes.
- The second though, is an attribute to the RandomWayPointModel and it is used to pick a destination point. Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/doxygen/classns3_1_1_random_waypoint_mobility_model.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, K. 
I saw your comment on the previous Google Group, and I tried it worked.
So basically, I initialized a pointer object cus I found the type of position allocator in RWP model is pointer.
`Ptr<ListPositionAllocator> positionAlloc = CreateObject<ListPositionAllocator> ();` 

`positionAlloc->Add(Vector (10,20,0.0));` //e.g. this is the first node..


So I used this method to build the position allocator, how do you think of it, is it correct?  P.S. I tried using only this allocator and I found the result is the same when I used TWO p.allocators.

Comment: @Konstantions Could you please have a look at [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629448/how-to-trace-the-nodes-movement-time-in-ns3) that I post? Many thanks.

Comment: @ShanHuang I would recommend using the officilal ns-3-users mailing list for support on ns-3. For ns-3 related issues, you have better chanche getting help there as it is focused on ns-3 compared to SF.

Comment: For the position allocator, I would say that ListPositionAllocator is not the best option for this unless you add several (tens) points in your allocator. You could use the List allocator for the initial position (the first time) but I would suggest to use RandomDisc or RandomRectangle position allocators for 'bounding' the RandomWaypointModel.

Comment: Oh @ Konstantions, thank you for the recommendation! I am always looking forward to finding the 'official community', but I haven't found it until you told me this. I will look into that!

Comment: For the 'bounding' the Randomwaypoint model I have a question, which I discussed with my supervisor, which is I am not sure the model needs a 'border' for the nodes ( e.g. using `RandomRectangle position allocators`) because I looked up in the [RWP model class reference](), it says like:

Comment: **This mobility model enforces no bounding box by itself; the PositionAllocator assigned to this object will bound the movement. If the user fails to provide a pointer to a PositionAllocator to be used to pick waypoints, the simulation program will assert.** 

I mainly use this model trying to simulate people's movement in the real world. So if in this scenario, which is the proper way to deal with the 'bonding issue'?  Because my supervisor told me in the real world there is no geometry restriction for people

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, there is no explicit bound attribute, as in other models. But you need to specify the PositionAllocator to select the next waypoint. You can use the RandomRectangle to be as big as you like to cove a whole city! I would suggest your supervisor to try to walk on water or through a wall. There are restrictions for people. This PositionAllocator will be the bounds of your 'reference area'. Nodes will move randomly (no restrictions) within that.