# How to trace the nodes movement time in ns3?

Tags: c++, ns-3

So basically, I used RandomwayPoint model in NS3 and I got the result of nodes like this:

```
/NodeList/5/$ns3::MobilityModel/CourseChange x = 10, y = 20
/NodeList/6/$ns3::MobilityModel/CourseChange x = 30, y = 40
/NodeList/7/$ns3::MobilityModel/CourseChange x = 50, y = 80
/NodeList/5/$ns3::MobilityModel/CourseChange x = 10, y = 20
/NodeList/6/$ns3::MobilityModel/CourseChange x = 30, y = 40
/NodeList/7/$ns3::MobilityModel/CourseChange x = 50, y = 80
/NodeList/5/$ns3::MobilityModel/CourseChange x = 10, y = 20
/NodeList/6/$ns3::MobilityModel/CourseChange x = 30, y = 40
/NodeList/7/$ns3::MobilityModel/CourseChange x = 50, y = 80
At time 2s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.2.4 port 9
At time 2.01596s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.3 port 49153
At time 2.01596s server sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.3 port 49153
At time 2.02464s client received 1024 bytes from 10.1.2.4 port 9
......
```

But how to record the time of the each node's movement? 
I think the most relevant code is about using `Simulator:: Now().GetSeconds()`
Here is the code I wrote:

```
     std::ostringstream oss2(std::ostringstream::ate);
     oss2.str("TimeStamp:");
     oss2 << Simulator::Now().GetSeconds ();
     std::cout << oss2.str() << "\t";
```

But I got the result equals to 0s. I felt confused about this, I would appreciate that if anyone can offer me a better solution and help me figure this out.

ManyThanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is correct, `Simulator::Now()` provides the time. You can print it in a single line, no need for four!

```
std::cout << "TimeStamp:" << Simulator::Now().GetSeconds() << "\t";
```

The fact that you got t=0sec, probably is due to the fact that the nodes do not 'change' after that. CourseChange callback is fired only during a change in the speed or velocity (direction). If the node is moving with constant speed, it will not fire.

Following your comment in the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593991/how-to-set-up-the-position-allocator-when-using-ramdomwaypoint-model-in-ns-3/44626768#44626768), you said you have used ListPositionAllocator. If you only have a single entry in the list, then it will not change apart from the initial at t=0 (what you see in the output).

Comment: Thanks@Konstantinos! That's true, you know after I got the output I found 
before the output line like `client send packet to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` the nodes' position **don't** change at all (which you can observe the code above) only after the output line the, the nodes' position start to change. 

But in the ListPositionAllocator I set up 3 entries(which I understand the entry you mentioned here is the node)

What I want to achieve here is to get the time that after each node's position changes, do you have some ideas to figure it out?

Comment: Suddenly I have an idea: 
Can I alter the code in the RWP model and there is one line `Time pause = Seconds (m_pause->GetValue ());` I was thinking to add a printout line after this printing out the pausing time and set up a timer to record the whole process. Because after each time pause, the direction will be changed which means the nodes' positions will be changed. Am I right?

Comment: No need to do that, because if there is a change, the trace source will fire and you can capture that. Currently the default pause time is 2sec and the speed is randomly selected between [0.3, 0.7] m/s. It may take a few seconds to reach each of the points you have in your list. For example to cover a distance of 100m, you would need ~200sec. Then it will go to the next waypoint, that would fire the trace source!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, @Konstantinos  I just posted a question in [Google group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ns-3-users/zY-0ndh_Lfw/discussion) Would you mind have a look?